# Script to sort google sheet tabs on a specific sheet in a shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I work off many google sheets with 10s of tabs.
I want to sort the tabs in alphabetical order.
I want to sort them on a weekly basis (i.e. Fridays at 11pm)
I would also like to have a Custom Menu function that allows me run the sort manually

so far I have found script that lets me sort on an active sheet.
But I don't know how I can create a script that lets met GET a specific Sheet from a LOCATION in my DRIVE an run the sort

```
function onOpen() {
  sortSheetsByName(); 
} 
function sortSheetsByName() {
  var aSheets = new Array();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var s in ss.getSheets()) {
    aSheets.push(ss.getSheets()[s].getName()); 
  } 
  if(aSheets.length) {
    aSheets.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < aSheets.length; i++) {
      var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName(aSheets[i]);
      if(theSheet.getIndex() != i + 1) {
        ss.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
        ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using `var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

   If instead you want to apply the script to a specific file on your drive, you need to access this spreadsheet with the method [SpreadsheetApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
2. If you want to run the script automatically at certain times, you need to bind to your function an [instalable time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). This allows you to specify how often and at what time your funciton shall run
3. If you want the function to appear in the Custom Menu, you can create one as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

Sample:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('My sort function', 'sortSheetsByName')
      .addToUi();
}

function sortSheetsByName() {
  ...
}
```

I recommend you to study the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) to obtain a deeper understanding for the code and be able to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function to take sheet id as parameter

```
function sortSheetsByName(sheetId) {
  var aSheets = new Array();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId)
  for (var s in ss.getSheets()) {
    aSheets.push(ss.getSheets()[s].getName()); 
  } 
  if(aSheets.length) {
    aSheets.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < aSheets.length; i++) {
      var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName(aSheets[i]);
      if(theSheet.getIndex() != i + 1) {
        ss.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
        ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then call it for fixed list of sheets like this

```
function sortAllSheets() {
  var sheetIdList = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']; // Here you provide ids or sheets you want to sort
  sheetIdList.map(sortSheetsByName);
}
```

Or, if you need it run for specific drive folder you can use something like this

```
function sortAllFolderSheets() {
    var files =  DriveApp.getFolderById('ID_OF_YOUR_LOCATION_FOLDER').getFiles();
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)
        sortSheetsByName(file.getId());
    }
}
```

And of course, if you want it to be periodic, you should set **sortAllSheets** or  **sortAllFolderSheets** as a trigger, like *ziganotschka* mentioned

Comment: function sortSheetsByName(sheetId) {
  var aSheets = new Array();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(1xQeywvKXs2KFMVdeojgIzl-Agui-dzNs9cnvrDGvzXQ)
  for (var s in ss.getSheets()) {
    aSheets.push(ss.getSheets()[s].getName()); 
  } 
  if(aSheets.length) {
    aSheets.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < aSheets.length; i++) {
      var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName(aSheets[i]);
      if(theSheet.getIndex() != i + 1) {
        ss.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
        ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1); 
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: not sure what I am doing wrong: I am getting SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (line 3, file "Code.gs")